# Communication Between Component and API using Redux- Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

> How can we get the data from the saga directly into our component ?

or

> Is this a pattern we should not follow and directly make a service/ api 
>   call from the component using some service layer.

I have been following [**this**](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/907) issue on git on if this is possible there are too many permutations and combinations and i am a bit confused ..

I tried this small example by refering [**this**](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/907#issuecomment-335294805)

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-sagas-demo-app-e96yee).

In this case when i try and return this

```
function* helloSaga() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('start of new Promise');
  });
}
```

and access it like this

```
let response = dispatch(action('SHOW')).then(data => {
  console.log(data); // i cannot get this to work say if this were a api response .
})
```

Nothing happens .

Is this pattern acceptable if yes then how can we make it work and what am i missing it

And if this pattern is an anti-pattern then making service calls from a layer like `getData()` should be enough from `componentDidMount()` .

Answer (score 0):

A generator function doesn't really return a value (or the promise in your case) as you'd expect with any "regular" function. It returns a generator-object that you can pause, continue, cancel etc.

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

The way to go with redux-saga in a web app would be:

1. Trigger an `action` like `"SHOW"` in your example
2. Have a `saga` take your action `"SHOW"`
3. The `saga` would then do the async API request
4. Once the API request is done, the `saga` dispatches another `action` (something like `FETCH_SUCCEEDED`
5. Handle the action in your reducer and store the response in the redux store.

Once it's stored in the redux store, you can select it from any react component you want to (use `connect` from redux for that)

Here's your stackblitz with a minimal example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-sagas-demo-app-4tpevb?file=index.js

For a production app, you'd want to wrap the API request in a `try{..}catch(){..}` and handle the error with a proper action like `FETCH_FAILED` and display an error message in your FE (if it effects the user).